# Unable to launch Angular app on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, package-name

I get the following error when I try to luanch my Angular app in my android app.

```css
06-15 13:49:15.037 9055-9055/? E/AppInfoBase: Exception when retrieving package:com.myPackage
                                              android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.myPackage
                                                  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:137)
                                                  at com.android.settings.applications.AppInfoBase.retrieveAppEntry(AppInfoBase.java:123)
                                                  at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.refreshUi(InstalledAppDetails.java:466)
                                                  at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.onActivityResult(InstalledAppDetails.java:435)
                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6452)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-15 13:49:15.110 1900-1900/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
```

What is the issue? Unable to debug and trace :( I see the Android manifets file, its proper!

Comment: Show code at which line getting issue

Comment: "Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?" doesn't this help you? Maybe check mistyped package name.

Comment: I did not type anything anywhere, its a cordova app I have created. I am wondering!